# Structure usage inside another structure

Tags: c, structure

Please check the code snippet given below. Pardon me if anything is wrong with the syntax or anything else. I am a newbie trying to learn structure usage in detail and I happened to come across the following sample. I just wanted to know how to access ***Stu_Details*** from ***Class_Details***

```
typedef struct {
int age;
int RollNo;
int Rank;
char Name[10];
}TypeStudent;

typedef struct {
char class_name[20];
TypeStudent Students[20];
}TypeClass;

const TypeStudent  Stu_Details[] = {
 { 3,   1,  18, "Mahesh"},
 { 3,   1,   7,  "Kumar"} 
 };

 const TypeClass Class_Details[]= {
 { "Class 10",     Stu_Details},  //two students details
 { "Class 8",                0}   //no student details attached 
 };
```

Comment: A compiler is the preferred method of checking your programs syntax. You don't actually access anything here, only try to initialize it. What is your *exact* problem?

Comment: Class_Details[0].Stu_details[0].Name, Class_Details[0].Stu_details[0].RollNo etc..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This one worked for me.

```
typedef struct {
    int age;
    int RollNo;
    int Rank;
    char Name[10];
}TypeStudent;

typedef struct {
    char class_name[20];
    TypeStudent *Students;
}TypeClass;

int main()
{

   const TypeStudent  Stu_Details[] = {
     { 3,   1,  18, "Mahesh"},
     { 3,   1,   7,  "Kumar"}
   };

   const TypeClass Class_Details[]= {
     { "Class 10",     Stu_Details},  //two students details
     { "Class 8",                0}   //no student details attached
   };

   printf("\r\nTest: %s",Class_Details[0].Students->Name);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 Class_Details[0].Students[0].Name
```

for exemple will be "Mahesh"

Comment: The name of the member variable is `Students`, not `Stu_details`, so correct would be `Class_Details[0].Students[0].Name`.